# How can i set default input variables for every request with grapqhql (amplify)

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I have multiple requests like this one:

```
await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(mutations.createSomething, { input: something }),
    )
```

Is it possible to add default variables to input to every request? (don´t mean headers)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own mutation and put a default value there:

```js
const createSomething = `mutation {
  createSomething(input: { field: "DEFAULT_VALUE" }) {
    id
  }
}`;

API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createSomething));
```